# Looping through custom taxonomy and display custom post types (Custom Post Type UI)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop

I am using Custom Post Type UI and Custom Fields plugins for the WordPress theme I am creating.

I have created a custom post type of price and I have created a custom taxonomy called price_types using Custom Post Type UI.

On my Prices page I can loop through the built in taxonomy 'Categories' easily using the code below:

```
$categories = get_terms('category');
foreach( $categories as $category ):
?>
  <section class="pricing">
    <h2><?php echo $category->name; // Print the cat title ?></h2>

  </section>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If I try and do the same for my custom taxonomy even though I have added entries I get nothing?

```
$categories = get_terms('price_types');
foreach( $categories as $category ):
?>
  <section class="pricing">
    <h2><?php echo $category->name; // Print the cat title ?></h2>

  </section>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: do you get anything if you echo print_r($category); I take it the remming '//' is not in your actual code?

Comment: or is it maybe... http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms

Comment: I don't get anything when using echo print_r($category); the // comment is not in my code.

Comment: did you try get_the_terms() instead of get_terms() - actually sorry ignore this if it works for categorys then surely the loop should work. Let me test it on mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this should retrieve all taxonomies terms including empty ones.

```
<?php
        $terms = get_terms('price_types',
            array(
                'hide_empty' => false,
                'orderby'    => 'name',
                'order'      => 'ASC'
            )
        );
        echo print_r($terms);
        foreach( $terms as $term ):
    ?>
  <section class="pricing">         
    <h2><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>
  </section>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: that seemed to do the trick! 

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 6 [name] => Ladies Styling [slug] => ladies-styling [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 11 [taxonomy] => price_types [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 0 ) ) 1

Ladies Styling

Does this mean that the term is empty? What does this actually mean?

Comment: Basically `echo print_r($terms)` shows the contents of the variable `$terms` you can remove this line `echo print_r($terms)`. It's only to test. I think maybe because your terms are empty, this is why they would not display, so `'hide_empty' => false` fixed this.